# What kind of plant do I have?

Tags: identification, succulents

[image: unidentified plant, some kind of succulent]

I bought this plant a while ago and I'm having trouble identifying it.  I thought it was a hen and chicks when I got it, but it seems to be growing out of control.  It doesn't need much water at all and is growing well in pretty dry soil.

Comment: Has this plant been kept somewhere shady, or has it been growing in full sun?

Comment: Definitely MORE light!!